# Getting 204 response before db action callback in expressjs, mongodb, inversifyjs

Tags: mongodb, typescript, express, observable, inversifyjs

I want to add new document to the mongodb and get an inserted id as response with 201 status, but when db.insertOne called I get response with 204 status code before tap works. Here is my controller

```
@controller('/stars')
export class StarController {

   constructor(@inject(TYPES.StarService) private starService: IStarService) {}

@httpPost('/')
public newStar(request: Request, response: Response) {
    this.starService.insert(request.body)
        .pipe(
            tap(result => response.status(201).json(result))
        ).subscribe();
}
}
```

In my StarService

```
@injectable()
export class StarService implements IStarService {
private mongoClient: MongoDBClient;

constructor(@inject(TYPES.MongoDBClient) mongoClient: MongoDBClient) {
    this.mongoClient = mongoClient;
}

 public insert(star) {
    return this.mongoClient.insertOne(star, 'stars');
}
```

In MongoDBClient

```
   public insertOne<T>(document: T, collectionName: string): Observable<ObjectID> {
    return from(
        this.db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(document))
        .pipe(
            map(
                (result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
                    return result.insertedId;
                }));
}
```

How can I get json response with correct status code and body

Comment: Hi Lilit.
As I understood  in your case  when you call to insert it works  but when you call insertOne  it returns 204?

Comment: Hi Armen.Thank you for your response. No, after 
`this.db.collection(collectionName).insertOne(document)` I immediately get 204 response.And after that `map(
                (result: InsertOneWriteOpResult) => {
                    return result.insertedId;
                })` works.

Comment: And when `response.status(201).json(result)` called I am getting error "can't set headers after they are sent"

Comment: it easy to catch, this error means that you already sent your http response header  and it can't be changed or overridden. it associated with your http response and doesn't meter what you use mongodb or ms sql or mysql, I recomend you manualy set your http header  and do not try  change it
like this 
 response.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/json"); and so one ...

Comment: sorry response.addHeader is a java code  on node js you can do  res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');